# How to merge objects base on same key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

I try merge object when they have same key. If they have same `model_name`, keep `model_name`, merge
`model_value`.
Here is the code:

```
let arr = [
   {
    model_name: 'random1',
    model_value: 'cloud',
    model_type: 1,
   },
   {
    model_name: 'random1',
    model_value: 'sea',
    model_type: 1,
   },
 {
    model_name: 'random2',
    model_value: 'tiger',
    model_type: 2,
   },
   {
    model_name: 'random2',
    model_value: 'lion',
    model_type: 2,
   },
   {
    model_name: 'random3',
    model_value: 'elephant',
    model_type: 3,
   }]
```

I want result look like below:

```
  arr = [
   {
    model_name: 'random1',
    model_value: ['cloud', 'sea'],
    model_type: 1,
   },
   {
    model_name: 'random2',
    model_value: ['tiger', 'lion'],
    model_type: 2,
   },
   {
    model_name: 'random3',
    model_value: ['elephant'],
    model_type: 3,
   }]
```

If object in array has same key model_name, then merge model_value.
How to achieve this, thanks

Comment: Would it be fine if `elephant` was also in an array? Or do you need it as a string?

Comment: Yes, `elephant` in an array is fine.

Comment: const newArr = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, { model_name, model_value }) => {
    if (!acc[model_name]) {
      acc[model_name] = { model_name, model_value: [model_value] }
    } else {
      acc[model_name].model_value.push(model_value)
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
)